# Lead acid battery charging too fast

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have an ebike. I usually charge my lead acid battery for 6 hours until the charger shows green light, and I can travel for 30 Km or so. But since last week, green light indicating full charge appears after only 2.30h, and I can only travel 10 Km max, on low speed. If I try to charge it with another charger, same thing happens. I tried everything, but I can't get the bike to charge after 2.30h. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Do the maintenance instructions for the ebike include anything about the battery, such as inspecting the electrolyte level?

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Insert appropriate expletive at the end of this sentence: *your battery is probably .....*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s time for a new battery. At least one cell in yours has lost capacity, probably the result of a broken plate or internal connection. The vibration experienced in E-vehicle applications is very hard on batteries.

There's no reasonable way to repair it, so recycle it and get a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. Will go to the shop ASAP, then...

Answer (score 0):

The faster you charge your battery the shorter life you can get from your battery (generally). When charging a lead acid battery, take into account the charging stages. Some chargers tell you the current stage of charge weather be in bulk, absorption, or float. Each stage requires CV or CC modes which your charger doesn’t have. Try charging slowly, it might help( lower the current ) ( I might be wrong but this all I can remember when working around lead acid batteries)

Comment: Thank you. Will try what you suggest, and if nothing improves, will replace them :(

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that a cell of your battery has failed with a high ESR, so that the overall voltage of your battery is lower when running, but higher when charging.  Unless it's a very old battery that requires maintenance, such as refilling cells regularly, the likely solution is to replace the battery.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and time. Everyone seems to be telling me the same thing : I will listen and replace the battery, as you suggest... It is just that the batteries are only 1 yr and a half, but it is true ebike can be tough for the batteries, with vibration and other things...